# using chatterbean AIML interpeter to make alice bot

Tags: java, tags, aiml

whenever i try to load the Alice aiml files i get various errors about the tags not being found, but when i fix thos errors i get an error i dont know how to fix. the aiml thing not being implemented, but wehen i look at the aiml class it is impementing it :?
my code:

```
public static String input()
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //System.out.println("you say>");
    String input = "";
    try 
    {
        input = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return input;
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
     Chat ch=new Chat();        
     AliceBotMother mother = new AliceBotMother();        
     mother.setUp();
     AliceBot bot = mother.newInstance();
     System.err.println(bot.respond("welcome"));
 while(true)
 {
     String input = Chat.input();
         // while the user saying 'bye'
         if(Chat.END.equalsIgnoreCase(input))
             break;
         // do some respond..
         System.err.println("Alice>" + bot.respond(input));
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chatterbean is an old Java program that is no longer supported.  You should the newer Java AIML 2.0 library Program AB at https://code.google.com/p/program-ab/

Comment: how did i not find this after hours of googling? thank you very much!